# fetch data from database in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from database. For that in controller I have created variables for table_name and select_fields as follows -

```
$tbl_name="user_master";
$select="'user_master.*', 'country.country_name','city.city_name','login_master.email_id','login_master.password'";
$users=$obj->getdata($tbl_name,$select);
```

In model I assigned these variables to query as follows -

Model -

```
public function getdata($tbl_name,$select)
{
    $users = DB::table($tbl_name)
                ->join('country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id')
                ->join('city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id')
                ->join('login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id')
                ->select($select)
                ->paginate(5);

    return $users;
}
```

But It is not working. It is showing error- Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
If I try as -

```
$users = DB::table('user_master')
                ->join('country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id')
                ->join('city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id')
                ->join('login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id')
                ->select('user_master.*', 'country.country_name','city.city_name','login_master.email_id','login_master.password')
                ->paginate(5);

return $users;
```

This above query working fine but when I assign select fields to variable it is not working.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: what are you getting in `$select` field

Comment: If I echo $select in model it gives output -  'user_master.*', 'country.country_name','city.city_name','login_master.email_id','login_master.password'

Comment: can you show me the error you get

Comment: yeah it is syntax error, but i need the full error message with query

Comment: at Connection->runQueryCallback('select `user_master`.`*,country`.`country_name,city`.`city_name,login_master`.`email_id,login_master`.`password` from `user_master` inner join `country` on `user_master`.`country_id` = `country`.`country_id` inner join `city` on `user_master`.`city_id` = `city`.`city_id` inner join `login_master` on `user_master`.`user_id` = `login_master`.`user_id` limit 5 offset 0', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that the coma (`,`) separating your selection of different table in the `select()` function is being read as a string, hence it breaks the SQL query. Your select is meant to be like this: `select('table1.*', 'table2.someColumn');` Notice the coma is not inside the single quote `''`

So try this:

```
    $select= ['user_master.*', 'country.country_name', 'city.city_name', 'login_master.email_id', 'login_master.password'];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried it but showing the same error

Comment: I edited my answer, so I built the select as an array. I haven't tested it. Try let see if that works

Comment: Yes It is working. Thanks. There is one more problem If I have to store joins in array and pass to model as we have passed $select array, so how it is possible?

Comment: I was away. Guess this is not coming too late :) As for the join you can try this: `$join = [ ['city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id'], ['login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id'], ['login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 'login_master.user_id'] ];`

Comment: It is not working. It shows error - Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(), called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo_laravel/app/Models/Userdata.php on line 64 and defined